# jQuery light box wont work with dynamically inserted images in chrome

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a website where you can upload an image into a database from a webpage, then PHP displays the images dynamically on to the page where you can click an image, then a jQuery light box will enlarge the image. Problem is, after I upload an image and try to enlarge it with the light box it will not display the image, only the overlay and exit button appear. This only happens in Chrome and not Firefox or IE.

Here is the jQuery Code.

```
    // image gallery light box
$('.overImg').click(function(){
    var $img = $(this);// the current image clicked
    var $imgH = $img.height(); 
    var $imgW = $img.width(); 
    var $thisLoc = $img.position(); // current images position on the page 
    var $desc = $img.attr('alt');// current images alt tag
    var $imgDes = $('.imgDes'); // container to hold images alt description
    var $copy = $img.clone().appendTo('body'); // a copy of the image appended to the copyholder div
    var $newImg = new Image();
    $newImg.src = $img.attr('src');
    var $newImgH = $newImg.height;
    var $newImgW = $newImg.width;
    var $window = $(window);
    var vMargin = 100;
    var hMargin = 0;
    var $windowHeight = $window.height() - vMargin;
    var $windowWidth = $window.width() - hMargin;



    // set image height and width to fit the screen
    //---------------------------------------------
    // if the images height or width is bigger than 
    // the screen size
    if(($newImgW > $windowWidth) || ($newImgH > $windowHeight)){
        // if the images width is bigger than
        // its height
        if($newImgW  > $newImgH){
            // set the new width to the width of the screen
            newWidth = $windowWidth;
            imgRatio = $newImgW / $windowWidth;
            newHeight =  $newImgH/imgRatio; 
            // set the height and width 
            // to the new values
            height = newHeight;
            width = newWidth;               
            // if the images height is still 
            // bigger than the screen size 
            if(newHeight>$windowHeight){
                // set the new height to the same height 
                // as the screen size
                newerHeight = $windowHeight;
                newerRatio = newHeight / $windowHeight;
                newerWidth = newWidth / newerRatio;
                height = newerHeight;
                width = newerWidth;
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = $windowHeight;
            ratio = $newImgH / $windowHeight;
            newWidth = $newImgW / ratio;
            height = newHeight;
            width = newWidth;
            if(width > $windowWidth){
                newerWidth = $windowWidth;
                newerRatio = newWidth / $windowWidth;
                newerHeight = newHeight / newerRatio;
                height = newerHeight;
                width = newerWidth;
            } 
        }
    } else {
        // if width and height isn't bigger than 
        // the screen just set the width and height
        // to the original height and width of the image
        width = $newImgW;
        height = $newImgH;
    }

    // enlarge width and height
    // to the biggest size possible
    var enlargeW = width;
    var enlargeH = height;            

    //Center the image by dividng the pages width and height 
    //by 2 then subtracting half of the current images width and height
    var centerW = ($(window).width()/2) - (enlargeW /2);
    var centerH = ($(window).height()/2) - (enlargeH /2);


    // background overlay
    var $overlay = $('.overlay');

    // image exit button
    var $exitImg = $('.exitImg');

    // image closes when 
    // exit button is clicked
    $exitImg.click(function(){
        closeImg();
    });         

    // function that shows and enlarges clicked image   
    function showImg(){

        // grab the distance from the top
        var $topPos = $(window).scrollTop();

        $copy
        .css({
            'position':'fixed',
            'left': $thisLoc.left, 
            // subtract the distance from the top
            // from the current images position
            // so images return to the correct
            // location
            'top': $thisLoc.top - $topPos,
            'border':'none'
        })
        .filter(':not(:animated)')
        // centering image
        .animate({
            'left':centerW,
            'top':centerH,
            'width':enlargeW, 
            'height':enlargeH,
            'overflow':'auto',
            'z-index':998
        },900,"easeOutBounce",function(){
            // Show the close button
            showCloseBtn();
            //show image description
            showImgDes();
        });
        $overlay.fadeIn(500);   

    } // end of showImg function            

    // Function to close opened image
    function closeImg(){
        var $topPos = $(window).scrollTop();

        $copy
        .filter(':not(:animated)')
        .animate({
            'left':$thisLoc.left,
            'top':$thisLoc.top - $topPos + 10, 
            'width':$imgW,
            'height':$imgH,
            'z-index':987
        },400,"linear",function(){
            // remove copy of image
            $copy.remove();         
        });
        // Hide the overlay
        $overlay.fadeOut(500);
        // Hide the close button
        hideCloseBtn();
        // Hide the desciption tag
        hideImgDes();
    }  // end of closeImg function

    // function to show close button
    function showCloseBtn(){
        // To prevent queue build up, we filter the animation.
        $exitImg.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({'top':0},300);
    }

    // function to show image description
    function showImgDes(){      
        // grab the image description DIV
        $imgDes.text($desc);
        // Center the image description  
        $centerDesW = ($(window).width() /2) - ($imgDes.width()/2);
        $imgDes
        .css({
            'left': $centerDesW
        })
        .filter(':not(:animated)').animate({'top':0},300);
    } 

    // hide the close button
    function hideCloseBtn(){
        $exitImg.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({'top':-111+"px"},400);  
    }

    // hide the image description
    function hideImgDes(){
        $imgDes.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({'top':-200+"px"},900);
    }

    showImg();

});
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: post a jsfiddle, better than just giving us a big block of code

Comment: Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/tbone1020/zLFuc/19/

Comment: works fine for me in Chrome 35, Chrome Canary 37, FF 29. What version of chrome are you using? Nice lightbox effect, btw, its pretty slick

Comment: Thanks! it's always good to hear people like my work. I'm also using Chrome 35 and FF29 but I actually just solved the problem myself, all I needed to do was make sure the new image() was loaded before I grabbed the height and width. Thanks for your help though.